# Set up FTP user with ProFTPD on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, authorization, proftpd

I want to set up a user "ftp" so they can upload and download files in my `/home/httpd/mysite/public_html` directory.

All files in `public_html` are owned by user "ftp" and in group "www-data" so the ftp user looks like so:

```
uid=108(ftp) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data),65534(nogroup)
```

When I try to connect via an FTP client I get:

```
530 Login incorrect.
ftp: Login failed.
```

What do I need to uncomment/add to the `proftpd.conf` file to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

Just had this problem with Ubuntu 12.04.2 and ProFTP. I had my FTP user's shell set to /bin/false and ProFTP wouldn't allow that to connect (it showed Error 530).

What I did was followed I uncommented this on my /etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf:

`RequireValidShell Off`

And I also added `/bin/false` to my /etc/shells file.

Restart ProFTP and you're good!

Hope this saves someone time.

Answer (score 0):

The error is mainly get when the user has a shell that is not listed in /etc/shells
Make sure the /bin/false is declared into /etc/shells